# Multiple definitions for WM_MOUSEWHELL in WinUser.h, yet message not generated

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

Here is a portion of WinUser.h

```
    #if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400) || (_WIN32_WINDOWS > 0x0400)
#define WM_MOUSEWHEEL                   0x020A
#endif
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500)
#define WM_XBUTTONDOWN                  0x020B
#define WM_XBUTTONUP                    0x020C
#define WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK                0x020D
#endif
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
#define WM_MOUSEHWHEEL                  0x020E
#endif

#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
#define WM_MOUSELAST                    0x020E
#elif (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500)
#define WM_MOUSELAST                    0x020D
#elif (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400) || (_WIN32_WINDOWS > 0x0400)
#define WM_MOUSELAST                    0x020A
#else
#define WM_MOUSELAST                    0x0209
#endif /* (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600) */
```

The two definitions for mouse-wheel 0x020A and 0x020E are highlighted in Visual Studio, i.e. compiler sees both. But that is not what concerns me as much as the definition of WM_MOUSELAST, which is also 0x020E (the one that compiler sees. The problem I am having is that, regardless of all readings and adjustments to code, I do not get any WM_MOUSEWHEEL message. What is going on, and what should I do?
Thanks.

I must add, all controls are buttons, even edit-controls are buttons. So, the question might be, windows does not generate mouse-wheel for a button even when in focus?

Comment: Sure two definitions? Are you joked?

Comment: I do not understand the comment. Are you saying this cannot be resolved?

Comment: WM_MOUSEWHEEL(0x020A) is not same as WM_MOUSEHWHEEL(0x020E) - Mouse Wheel vs. Mouse H Wheel. And without code, I dont see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Oh man. Thank you so much. What a silly error. There is no problem. I copied the one with H (do not know what it is), from documentation. Now that I corrected it, everything is working great. Thanks for taking the time to explain the error.